# php look for string in address bar, replace body contents accordingly

Tags: php, html

I am looking for the php "header" code and in-html-body-phpsnippet which will look for an exact string such as "redwidget" or "bluewidget" "greenwidget" etc in the address bar, and *modify the output of the in-body* `<phpsnippet>` **based on which of those strings is there in the address bar**

... in other words, I can define a list of parameters to look for in the address bar, and the `<phpsnippet>` will modify the in-body html output based on which it finds

ALSO if it finds none of them, there is a default or "fallback" output

What would the header script and also the in-body  be?

**My goal** is to change the image displayed on a page based on which parameter it finds in the address bar

***Begin Example listing of outputs:
exact string "redwidgets" found in address bar -> `<phpsnippet>` outputs "/images/redwidget.jpg"

or exact string "greengoblin" found in address bar -> `<phpsnippet>` outputs "/images/greengoblin.jpg"

or exact string "bluewidgets" found in address bar -> `<phpsnippet>` outputs "/images/bluesteel.jpg"

or None of the above exact strings found in address bar -`<phpsnippet>` outputs "/images/defaultplaceholderimagethingy.jpg"

***End example

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$validKeywords = array("a", "b");
//ternary if/else: condition ? this if true : otherwise this;
$keyword = isset($_GET['keyword']) && in_array($_GET['keyword'], $validKeywords) ? $_GET['keyword'] : "defaultplaceholderimagethingy";
//format the output with sprintf and store it for later use
$output = sprintf("<img src='images/%s' alt='%s' />", $keyword.".jpg", "descriptive text");
print $output;
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: awesome, does everything I need now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use GET parameters?

```
http://myurl/?phpsnippet=redwidget
```

In your code:

```
if (isset($_GET['phpsnippet']) {
    // use $_GET['phpsnippet'] which, in this case, equals 'redwidget'
} else {
    // display default
}
```

Comment: The output should not match the parameter value exactly. Rather, the parameter indicates which output to use (I define the outputs).In my examples above you will notice that the image URLs (the outputs) were not exact replicas of the parameter string. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for the answer anyways because for now I can simply change the image names to match the parameter and I think this will work

Comment: You can use if ($_GET['phpsnippet'] == 'something') { // use custom output }

Comment: Is there a header code that needs to go on the page? I'm getting a parse error syntax error when I put your first suggestion into my body contents. Here is my code `<img alt="" src="http://mydomain.net/wp-content/uploads/<?if (isset($_GET['keyword']) {
    // will use image name that matches $_GET['keyword']
} else {
    echo 'DefaultImageFileName';}?>.jpg" border="0" width="300" height="314" />`

Answer (score 0):

**Ok I ALMOST figured this one out...**

**Here is my header code:**

```
if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];

}
```

**And my in-body html/php which replaces the image based on the keyword parameter:**
`<img alt="" src="http://takeherhometonight.net/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo $keyword; ?>.jpg" border="0" width="300" height="314" />`

**The only thing I can't get with the above is a DEFAULT image, should a keyword parameter not be present.... any ideas?**

Comment: `$keyword = isset($_GET['keyword']) ? $_GET['keyword'] : "defaultValue";`

Comment: Thanks that worked! Would you by chance know how to define a list of "acceptable" keyword variables? and IF they keyword passed along doesn't match any of those "acceptable" variables than it outputs the defaultValue?